# How do I populate an entire page with <div>'s using javascript and/or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     *POPULATE PAGE WITH DIVS*
});
```

I found a question very similar to mine and someone answered to just paste a ton of divs inside the html but I do not want to do this.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

That's my HTML, I want to use javascript / jQuery to add divs of class square until the page is filled.

Something along the lines of:

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    $('.container').add('.square');
}
```

I just can't seem to get the syntax right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    $('.container').add('div').addClass('square');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    if(i % 5 == 0)           
       $('.container').append('<div class="square" />').css({clear: 'both'});
    else
       $('.container').append('<div class="square" />');
}
```

Change 5 to whatever you want :)

Comment: Ok, the second one with append works for adding them all on the top line. How can I make it so it drops down after a certain width or number of divs?

Comment: Using CSS. If you use float: left on the square and set a width for container it should work.

Answer (score 1):

For a little variation, you might construct the string of elements and add them all at once rather than add them one by one, with something like this:

```
var result = "";
var format = "<div class='square'></div>";
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  result += format;
}
$('.container').append(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

or this

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
    $("<div/>").addClass("square").appendTo($(".container").eq(0));
}
```